# i want to show all tags and stories of tag with pagination of stories

Tags: laravel, pagination

hi i am looking solution for :

- display all tags and each tag has stories
- display stories of tag with pagination of 4

something like :

loves

- title 1
- title 2
- title 3
- title 4

horror

- title 1
- title 2
- title 3
- title 4

.
.
.

Tag model:

```
public function stories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Story');
}
```

Controller :

```
public function index() {
    $stories = Story::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('welcome',compact('stories','tags'));
}
```

View

```
        @foreach($tags as $tag)   
            <div id="myCarousel{{$tag->id}}" class="carousel slide row justify-content-md-center" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="0">
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <h1 class="text-center p-2">{{$tag->name}}</h1>
                    <div class="carousel-inner center">
                        <div class="row">
                            @foreach($tag->stories()->paginate(4) as $story)
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                                    <div class="card story">
                                        <img class="card-img-top" src="/imgs/story/{{$story->image}}">
                                        <div class="card-block">
                                            <figure class="profile">
                                                <img src="/imgs/user/{{$story->image($story->user_id)}}" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
                                            </figure>
                                            <h4 class="card-title mt-3"> {{$story->title}} </h4>
                                            <div class="meta">
                                                By : <a> {{$story->author}} </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer">
                                            <small>Last updated  </small>
                                            <a href="{{route('story.show',$story->id)}}" class="btn btn-secondary float-right btn-sm">show</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel{{$tag->id}}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel{{$tag->id}}" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <br>        
        @endforeach
```

i want something like carousel multiple items

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slnZ3.png)

Comment: Can you please tell us more about the specific problem you're having? Are you getting an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: i don't have errors but i can't display all stories of one tag with 4 stories in page

Comment: Can you please tell us what **is** displaying? It helps to state "I am expecting X, but I am getting Y." [More about asking a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)